# C++ Warning only on 1 machine: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int'

Tags: c++

I am getting

```
g++ -O3 cache-l1-line.cpp -o cache-l1-line -lrt
cache-l1-line.cpp: In function 'int main()':
cache-l1-line.cpp:33:58: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat]
```

On my schools sunfire server ... but not my my machine (Arch Linux). Why might that be. The line in question seems to be

```
printf("%d, %1.2f \n", i * sizeof(int), totalTime/TIMES);
```

Where i is defined:

```
for (int i = 4; i <= MAX_STRIDE/sizeof(int); i*=2)  {
```

Whats the problem: **[full source on GitHub](https://github.com/jiewmeng/cs3210-assign1/blob/85f80b274ebb46efd58b36d4180fd4b024a3ee6d/cache-l1-line.cpp)** (link to revision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 64-bit architecture expressions evaluate to 64-bit. Thus the proper specifier in that architecture would be %llu. Or conversely the expression should be casted to the width and type expected by the specifier %d.

EDIT: %llu instead of %lld -- thanks for comment.

The expression (i * size_t) has different width and type in different architectures;
it's (unsigned int) apparently in your i3 -system and (unsigned long long) in your i7 -system.

Comment: Ok, but why does it not throw any warnings on my machine (Core i3/Arch Linux), but it does on the school's (Core i7/Ubuntu). Same makefile is used which calls g++, so same compiler also ... does different version of compiler make a difference? It seems like its more correct to give a warning?

Comment: You could try to add -c -m32 on the Core i7/Ubuntu to get rid of the warning. However the object can't probably be linked to anything useful, as this command produces 32-bit binaries and your system has 64-bit libraries (as default) and the corresponding header files.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. You should always cast such "special" types to the ones expected by your `printf` format:

```
printf("%d, %1.2f \n", (int)(i * sizeof(int)), totalTime/TIMES);
```

Note: some people prefer digging into their library to see what the types are typedef-ed to, and use the appropiate type in the format string. However, this has two problems: first, it can be different on another compiler. Second, a `size_t` is not a `long`, it's a `size_t`. Thus, from a more formal point of view, you'll always have a type mismatch because there is no format argument that takes a `size_t`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in "size_t" but that the result of the expression (int * ...) is 64-bit in that particular architecture.

Comment: `size_t` is a typedef for an unsigned integer type so `%u` with an appropriate length modifier can be a correct format specifier for `size_t`. In the current version of C++ you can use `%zu` which is guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: Ok, but why does it not throw any warnings on my machine (Core i3/Arch Linux), but it does on the school's (Core i7/Ubuntu). Same makefile is used which calls `g++`, so same compiler also ... does different version of compiler make a difference? It seems like its more correct to give a warning?

Answer (score 0):

Normally printf is not type safe this means that if you have something like this :

```
struct Point {int x, int y} point;
printf("%d", point);
```

It will compile but will probably crash when executed.But gcc has an extension that allows cheking the format string with the arguments.
"%d" expects an int but "i * sizeof(int)" is of type long unsigned int that's why you are getting a warning.